# Synchronous or Asynchronous Rxjava inside the Worker (from WorkManager component) what's the right choice?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I'm new to the new architecture component WorkManager, I do my API calls via Retrofit and RxJava.

My use case here is to get new posts from the Backend, then show notification, and update a widget.

So the code inside doWork() method from the Worker class, may look like something like this.

```
@NonNull
  @Override
  public Result doWork() {
    AppDependencies appDependencies = new AppDependencies((Application) getApplicationContext());
    Repository repository = appDependencies.getRepository();

    repository.getNewPosts()
        .flatMap(newPosts -> repository.inserPosts(newPosts).toObservable())
        .doOnError(Timber::e)
        //if success - > return  Result.SUCCESS,
        // -> show notification
        // -> update widget
        // error-> return Result.Failure
        .dontKnowWhatBestNextThing; //blocking or subscribing

    //if we reached here then Retry
    return Result.RETRY;
  }
```

My Question is what is the right way to use a RxJava code inside the Worker Class because the doWork() method has a return value, so Do I have to make Rx code Synchronous.

if I'm using the nonblocking Rx approach, how can I return value (Success - Failure - Retry)

Comment: Inside the lambda, we can obviously return any of the either statuses - Success, Failure or Retry only making sure that the same line is in the last line of execution.

Comment: @Debdeep could you please make it more clear with some code

Comment: use lambda with open braces inside `onError` or `onSuccess` and since we know either condition works and are probably the last one in chaining, inside braces do your work and in the last line, return the respective status to `WorkManager`

Comment: 'return Result.RETRY' at the end is okay and should reach only on rare cases. Mostly you would want to return the status from inside.

Comment: BTW, obtaining a reference to the `Application` by casting the application context is not guaranteed to work. I've mostly seen it fail in emulators, but also very rarely on real devices. It's safer to set a static field in the application's `onCreate` and provide a static getter.

Comment: can you share the last result with us, I'm lost and I need some hints

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since WorkManager version `1.0.0-alpha12` they added a new artifact called `work-rxjava2` that includes [`RxWorker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/RxWorker) class exactly for this purpose. It is a special case of `ListenableWorker` expecting `Single<Result>`.

To implement it, first make sure you include correct artifacts to your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
   implementation "android.arch.work:work-rxjava2:$work_version"
}
```

And implement your `RxWorker`:

```
class MyRxWorker(context : Context, params : WorkerParameters) : RxWorker(context, params) {

    val remoteService = RemoteService()

    override fun createWork(): Single<Result> {
        return remoteService.getMySingleResponse()
                .doOnSuccess { /* process result somehow */ }
                .map { Result.success() }
                .onErrorReturn { Result.failure() }
    }
}
```

Comment: What the RemoteService is ? 
Can you explain with more details please ? 
Because I get stuck with this issue for couple days

Comment: remote service is just some example service you might use to return some value wrapped in Single type.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** WorkManager now officially supports an `RxWorker`. Take a look at the answer above for more information.

`doWork` happens on a background thread. So it's safe to block. You should wait for the `Observable` to complete before you return a `Result`.

We are also working on making this easier with asynchronous APIs. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make the Rx code synchronous. The documentation for [doWork](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker.html#doWork()) is minimal, but the description

> Override this method to do your actual background processing.

implies that it's expected or at least allowed to block. And of course, you cannot know what `doWork` should return until the network request has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
You should use RxWorker or SettableFuture for async job

This is my solution for getting current location. Working like a charm

```
class LocationWorker(context: Context, private val workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
ListenableWorker(context, workerParams) {

lateinit var mFuture: SettableFuture<ListenableWorker.Result>
private var fusedLocationProviderClient = FusedLocationProviderClient(context)

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi", "MissingPermission")
override fun startWork(): ListenableFuture<Result> {
    val uniqueId = workerParams.inputData.getString(UNIQUE_ID_KEY)
    mFuture = SettableFuture.create()
    Timber.d("mFutureStart")
    fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
        Timber.d("location == $location")
        if (location != null) {
            mFuture.set(Result.success())
        } else mFuture.set(Result.failure())
      }
    return mFuture
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both Rxjava and Coroutine with Work Manager. Have a look at this [Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/workmanager-basics-how-to-use-workmanager-with-rxjava2-kotlin-coroutines-c2a317197038) post. Hopefully it will help you. Thank you.